# Bluetooth Earbuds pair, but won't connect to Win10 PC

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth

When trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy buds+ to my PC using the onboard bluetooth adapter, I manage to pair them - though get a "That didn't work. Make sure your bluetooth device is still discoverable, then try again" message. I am able to connect them to other devices and my Win10 laptop, the problem only seems to appear with my (fairly old) PC.

The BT on my PC is older obviously, Bluetooth 3.0, but I haven't been able to find any mention of compatibility issues for the buds (The laptop, which connects, has BT 4.0).

Drivers seem to be the latest still existing. Restarting the BT/PC, re-pairing, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As descrined on the product page (https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/galaxy-buds-plus/specs/) it has BT 5.0 module. Even it should be backward capable it may not work with BT 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seemed to have been with windows itself - after a completely fresh windows install on a clean drive (due to unrelated reasons) it paired and connected properly without any further installations or driver downloads.